Why is my Website navigation working on live server but not when deployed
For my school project we are adding navigation to simple websites with javascript. I'm using Visual Studio Code and live server extension. When I run the website through live server extension it works fine.Here
However when i deploy to github and visit the site, the navigation does not appear and i get a 404 errorhere
This is my folder structure
this is my menu.js file that sits in the scripts folder

const root = "/WSOA3028A_2583750"

const menuItems = [
    {name: "Home", href: root + "/index.html"},
    {name: "Blog", href: `${root}/Blogs/index.html`},
    {name: "Essays", href: `${root}/Essays/index.html`},
    {name: "Portfolio", href: `${root}/Portfolio/index.html`},
    {name: "Design", href: `${root}/Design/index.html`},
    {name: "About", href: `${root}/About/index.html`},
];
export function initialise(currentPage){

    console.log("worked")
    const nav = document.querySelector("header > nav")
    const ul = document.createElement("ul")
    for(let menuItem of menuItems)
    {
        const li = document.createElement("li")
        if(currentPage != menuItem.name)
        {
            const a = document.createElement("a")
            a.innerText = menuItem.name
            a.setAttribute("href", menuItem.href)
            li.appendChild(a)

        }
        else{
            li.innerText = menuItem.name
        }
        ul.appendChild(li)
    }
    nav.appendChild(ul)

    
}


this is where i call the menu.js script in my index.html file that sits outside the folders

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta name="author" content="Cameron Morgan">
  <meta name="description" content="This is the index page of the website displaying the portfolio and blogs for Cameron Morgan in the course Interactive Media  ">
  <meta name="robots" content="index,follow">
  <meta name="keywords" content="Web Development, Game Development, Interactive, Blog, Portfolio, Essay, Design">

    <meta property="og:title" content="Cameron Morgan Portfolio Website">
    <meta property="og:description" content="Welcome to Cameron Morgan's Portfolio Website, here you can find his portfolio of work, including games, websites, blogs, analysis.">
    
    <meta property="og:url" content="https://wits-digital-arts-interactive-media.github.io/WSOA3028A_2583750/">

  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="Images/coffee.png">
  <script type="module">
    import { initialise } from "./Scripts/menu.js";
    initialise("Home"); // Call the initialise function with a test argument
</script>
  <title>Interactive Media Website</title>

  
  


</head>

Chrome throws up CORS errors
Access to script at 'file:///C:/Users/camer/IM_GITHUB/WSOA3028A_2583750/Scripts/menu.js' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, isolated-app, chrome-extension, chrome, https, chrome-untrusted.
and
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED

why would a deployed project use file:///C:/? You've deployed it wrong

This is a deployment issue. It looks like locally, your scripts folder is called Scripts, but on GitHub it's called scripts. Addresses are case-sensitive. Renaming your scripts folder on GitHub to Scripts should fix this issue.
